# openssl commands equivalent in python?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, openssl, private-key

I'm currently getting a private key with

`openssl pkcs8 -in file.key -inform DER`

And for some cer file

`openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in file.cer`

I can handle the extraction calling the commands on the terminal from python but I would prefer to do it with python libraries.

I looked for examples with *pyopenssl* but I didn't find something really similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

**How can I achieve the same result using python libraries?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using python cryptography didn't work for me I looked for an alternative package.

I found using `chilkat` is exactly what I needed. It has pkcs8 support and it's really fast.

My code is as follows

```
def get_private_key(filepath, password):
    pkey = chilkat.CkPrivateKey()
    pkey.LoadPkcs8EncryptedFile(filepath, password)
    return pkey.getPkcs8Pem()


def get_certificate_and_serial(filepath):
    cert = chilkat.CkCert()
    cert.LoadFromFile(filepath)
    serial = unhexlify(cert.serialNumber())
    return cert.exportCertPem(), serial.decode('utf-8')
```

Chilkat can be found [**here**](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/python.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [cryptography.io](http://cryptography.io). There's [DER certificate loading](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.load_der_x509_certificate) and [private key loading](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#der) supports PKCS#8 format.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out